# Bulk getEditResponseUrl() for Shared Forms with Python

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-api-python-client

What we'd like to do is iterate over all shared forms on a Google account (potentially hundreds), over which we'd like to, using Python, then call the `getEditResponseUrl()` function for each `FormResponse`, which seems only accessible via Google Apps Script, which we could presumably just call in Python using `execute()` per https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python.

However, it seems like the Apps Script with this behavior would need to be included in each shared form first, else the function in question won't exist as far as the client library is concerned; is there a way to call, for example, `getEditResponseUrl()` and other functions that are part of `FormResponse` and `FormApp` objects using any kind of Python client library or HTTP API, rather than having it exclusively found in the context of Google Apps Scripts and explicitly defined in the form beforehand? Thanks!

Comment: There is no Forms REST API, so you must use Apps Script to act on various Google Forms. You could certainly use a service account to execute a script project that collects edit url information for a users' forms. You can use the Apps Script API to execute this from a non-Google environment, and then consume the collected information as you wish. I don't see why you would need any of the user's Forms to have an Apps Script project.

Comment: @tehhowch thanks for your response. As I started digging deeper, it seemed to me that one centralized script should have the power to iterate over all shared forms and their `FormResponse`s rather than having each form carry its own copy of the script, though I haven't gotten far enough to test yet; is this the idea you're suggesting?

Comment: Yep. You can then use that single script project externally via the apps script API.

Comment: Note that service accounts cannot use the Apps Script API - I should not have suggested that.

Comment: @tehhowch thanks; we're not planning on using Service Accounts, just the account itself via OAuth2. The Quickstart for it works, just having issues now getting `scripts.run` to work; know why this might be? Some folks have said this error can happen if the script is associated with the wrong project, but all old questions suggest `Resources > Developer Console Project` was the way to fix, but now it's been replaced by `Resources > Cloud Platform Project...`, which doesn't let us link the console project?

Comment: You can probably get better help for that issue as its own question. I would start with the summary https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#step_2_set_up_the_common_cloud_platform_project